# Send URL file (website shortcut) as an email attachment

Tags: perl, email, url, hyperlink, email-attachments

How can I send an URL file (website link) as an attachment that mailer application will recognize this file as a valid file and allow to open a website with the URL saved in such attachment file?

[image]

When I attached `.url` file created by Google Chrome as `application/x-url` file with `file.url` file name, none of my mailer applications recognized this file as a valid/known file.

Comment: Which perl module are you using to send the mail?

Comment: @HåkonHægland - I will accept any working solution with any library. I personally use my own code using Microsoft Graph for sending emails, but I am open to any working solution.